# JavaFX + AWT Canvas

Tags: javafx, awt

I read that running AWT With JavaFX is a bad idea.
But we have an old application that runs on Swing and uses the AWT canvas(Cannot change due to an external library that uses the canvas)

Is it really such a horrible idea?
Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 12):

**Update**

Although the code in this answer used to work on Windows with an earlier version of JavaFX, I retested the same same code on OS X 10.9.5 + JavaFX 8u72 and *the code no longer works*.

The line `swingNode.setContent(awtInitializerTask.get());` which instructs the JavaFX thread to wait on the awt thread to initialize the awt canvas never returns, blocking execution and startup of the app.

---

Just put your AWT canvas in a [SwingNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html) and watch your thread management and you'll be fine.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

public class AwtCanvasWrapper extends Application {
    private static final int W = 200;
    private static final int H = 100;

    @Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final AwtInitializerTask awtInitializerTask = new AwtInitializerTask(() -> {
            JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
            jPanel.add(new CustomAwtCanvas(W, H));

            return jPanel;
        });

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(awtInitializerTask);

        SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        swingNode.setContent(awtInitializerTask.get());

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(swingNode), W, H));
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }

    private class AwtInitializerTask extends FutureTask<JPanel> {
        public AwtInitializerTask(Callable<JPanel> callable) {
            super(callable);
        }
    }

    private class CustomAwtCanvas extends Canvas {
        public CustomAwtCanvas(int width, int height) {
            setSize(width, height);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2;
            g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g2.fillRect(
                0, 0, 
                (int) getSize().getWidth(), (int) getSize().getHeight()
            );
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.drawString("It is a custom canvas area", 25, 50);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

[image: uglycanvas]

**Related Question**

- [Interoperability between Graphics2D and GraphicsContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071904/interoperability-between-graphics2d-and-graphicscontext)

**Answering some additional questions**

> But that one is for swing components.

Yes, but awt components can be wrapped in Swing components.

> furthermore It says in the docs that it should not be used of heavyweight components

Regardless, it seems to work for me, your mileage may vary.

> performance is crucial for my app

Then try the approach with your app and check:

1. The painting is reliable.
2. The performance is acceptable.

If either of the above checks fail then you may need to use a different approach (though I do not know what that approach would be, maybe just spawn Frame as a new window in which to include the the AWT canvas content rather than embedding the canvas inside the JavaFX scene).

Comment: But that one is for swing components, furthermore It says in the docs that it should not be used of heavyweight components, the canvas is one of the most heavyweight components there is, and performance is crucial for my app.

Comment: Updated answer based on comment.  I'd also request that if you like to dispute answers, that's fine, but if you do so, please try to include code for your failed attempt or post an answer with a superior approach (i.e. please don't put the onus on the answerer to prove that their answer is right, instead do your work to prove that the answer is wrong).

Comment: Yes, the code in this answer no longer works, probably due to some implementation change in JavaFX since the answer was created.  I have updated the answer to note this.