# Looking for a JavaFX timeline chart

Tags: charts, javafx

I've searched to no avail. I'm looking for a JavaFX example of a timeline chart similar to [this](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line). Just wondering if anyone has seen the like.

Comment: You can create diagrams like that with the JFreeChart library. There is a [question on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691320/how-i-can-use-jfreechart-with-javafx2) that has a answer that describes how to add the diagrams to JavaFx, at least for javafx-8, which should officially be released March this year.

Comment: Thanks @fabian. I'm actually trying to get away from JFreeChart.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will help: http://harmoniccode.blogspot.de/2013/12/dateaxis310.html

Comment: Thanks. What I'm really looking for is that kind of 2 chart look with a larger chart on the bottom and a chart with a smaller time window on the top. I have a lot of data to display, and a single chart is slightly cumbersome. Although, I did find a component developed by  Jason Winnebeck that handles zooming in and out as well as panning. If interested, you can find it [here](http://gillius.org/).