# Improve performance with 3K point on scatter chart

Tags: javafx

I was doing tests on a scatter chart in java fx, I saw that with 2000 points it takes a few seconds. How can I optimize performance?

I have a chart with on the y-axis numbers, while in x it has strings

I was trying to use a canvas above the chart to draw, but I wanted to know if you know any better way

Comment: [tag:jfreechart] easily handles thousands of points in a `Canvas`; more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44141878/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16697279/230513).

Comment: solved with canvas, thank you